# Javascript - sleep() in for loop

Tags: javascript, sleep

I have this script:

```
var array = [];
array[0] = 'http://facebook.com/';
array[1] = 'http://instagram.com/';
array[2] = 'http://twitter.com';

$(document).ready(function()
{
    for(i=0; i<= 2; i++)
    {
        $('#ifr').attr('src', array[i]);
        // sleep here for 0,5 second
    }
});
```

And how I can stop this loop for 0.5 second?

Comment: there is no sleep in javascript....

Comment: @Pamblam So give me an alternative in javascript.

Comment: @blex can u give me an example?

Comment: @Majkson You've got 2 answers right below and they both work. Choose the one you like.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `setTimeout` for this purpose,

```
for(i=0; i<=2; i++) {
  setTimeout(function(i) {
    $('#ifr').attr('src', array[i]);
  },500 * i,i);
  //1000 ms is 1 sec, here I have give 0.5 seconds as a delay.
}
```

There is no need to create scope per iteration for handling the closure problem. You can use the third parameter of `setTimout` to set the argument of `callBack` function.

Answer (score 2):

```
(function rec(i){
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('#ifr').attr('src', array[i]);
        if(i <= 2) rec(i+1);
    }, 5000);
})(0);
```

EDIT: added `if(i <= 2)` so that it doesn't recurse forever.. this will stop it after 2 iterations..

Comment: 5000 ms should be 500 ms

Comment: yea i just added that.

Comment: how did i go from +3 to -1 ?

Comment: Why would you recursively call the `rec` function, when you can just implement `setInterval` instead of `setTimeout`?

Comment: I like the setTimeout, don't have to track the timer and clearinterval that way